# Missing region in AWS rekognition in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

```
//Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
//PDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0 (For details, see https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rekognition-developer-guide/blob/master/LICENSE-SAMPLECODE.)


   const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
   const bucket        = 'bucket' // the bucketname without s3://
   const photo_source  = 'source.jpg'
   const photo_target  = 'target.jpg'
   const config = new AWS.Config({
     accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
     secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
     region: process.env.AWS_REGION
   })
   const client = new AWS.Rekognition();
   const params = {
     SourceImage: {
       S3Object: {
         Bucket: bucket,
         Name: photo_source
       },
     },
     TargetImage: {
       S3Object: {
         Bucket: bucket,
         Name: photo_target
       },
     },
     SimilarityThreshold: 70
   }
   client.compareFaces(params, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     } else {
       response.FaceMatches.forEach(data => {
         let position   = data.Face.BoundingBox
         let similarity = data.Similarity
         console.log(`The face at: ${position.Left}, ${position.Top} matches with ${similarity} % confidence`)
       }) // for response.faceDetails
     } // if
   });
```

Above code is from official aws webpage (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/faces-comparefaces.html). The code is for implementing comparing faces in image using node js. When comparing images using the above code a error occurs which says missing region on config. Then when i checked the code eventhough config object is created in this code but it is not being used anywhere. Can someone tell me where i must use the config object. If the error is appearing due to any other reason please tell me the reason

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.AWS_REGION` on this system? Is it undefined? Typically, you would use `AWS.config.update({ region: x, accessKeyId:y, secretAccessKey:z });` Having said that, if the AWS_xxx environment variables are set then you don't need to configure them explicitly at all; the SDK will pull them from your environment.

Comment: Actually i directly inserted my accesskeyid and secretAccesKey in the code itself. But in the example given (which i used) by the aws documentation only created the client object, and it is not used for `AWS.Rekognition`. I think the example code in the documentation is incomplete or wrong. An when i used `AWS.confif.update()`  i successfully connected to the API. So thanks